# Powershell list ftp certificate thumbprint

Tags: powershell, iis, ftp

I'm in the process of using powershell to audit certificate expiry.

One of the areas we're looking at is IIS site bindings inclusing FTP.

Now when I list out IIS sites, retrieve the thumbprint and then match with a certificate, it appears no FTP site information is pulled out...

```
$DaysToExpiration = 7

$expirationDate = (Get-Date).AddDays($DaysToExpiration)

$sites = Get-Website | ? { $_.State -eq "Started" } | % { $_.Name }
$certs = Get-ChildItem IIS:SSLBindings | ? {
           $sites -contains $_.Sites.Value
         } | % { $_.Thumbprint }

Get-ChildItem CERT:LocalMachine/My | ? {
  $certs -contains $_.Thumbprint -and $_.NotAfter -lt $expirationDate
}
```

The above does list the FTP site in the $sites variable but only the web site(s) SSL details are ever listed...

When certificates are added to an FTP site it's not performed in the same way as with at web site and I'm guessing this is the reason that no SSL details for the FTP site is extracted.

Does anyone know how to get at the thumbprint of the cert bound to an FTP site in powershell?

Thanks,

James

Comment: With TLS (SSL is obsolete and is replaced with TLS 1.2 or 1.3) the certificate is never transferred.  The server sends a TLS certificate block with names of the usable certificates.  The client than looks up the names in the client stores.  So you can capture the names of the certificates with a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler by looking at the certificate block,.